# How to Download the file which is uploaded locally

Tags: sapui5

I was going through the samples of Upload Collections :

[Sample from Docs](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.UploadCollection/sample/sap.m.sample.UploadCollectionVersioning)

Here I tried uploading a PDF file which has uploaded and shown as :

[image: Uploaded PDF and marked]

On selection `Download` enables and saw the code for download is as:

```
onDownloadItem: function() {
            var oUploadCollection = this.byId("UploadCollection");
            var aSelectedItems = oUploadCollection.getSelectedItems();
            if (aSelectedItems) {
                for (var i = 0; i < aSelectedItems.length; i++) {
                    oUploadCollection.downloadItem(aSelectedItems[i], true);
                }
            } else {
                MessageToast.show("Select an item to download");
            }
        },
```

It doesn't download any , but when i tried downloading other preexisting files, downloads successfully.

May I know why the local uploaded files doesn't download ?

Does the uploaded files needed any extra attributes ? as the existing one's have few such as:

```
            "documentId" : "64469d2f-b3c4-a517-20d6-f91ebf85b9da",
            "fileName" : "Screenshot.jpg",
            "mimeType" : "image/jpg",
            "thumbnailUrl" : "",
            "url" : "test-resources/sap/m/demokit/sample/UploadCollection/LinkedDocuments/Screenshot.jpg",.....
```

But when uploaded a new these all are empty in the code:

```
"documentId": jQuery.now().toString(), // generate Id,
                    "fileName": sUploadedFile,
                    "mimeType": "",
                    "thumbnailUrl": "",
                    "url": "".......
```

I am clueless on how to download files uploaded locally , any guiding links are much appreciated ...TIA

+1 Q --> May I How generally are uploaded files saved to DB ?

I have gone through docs but couldn't find any solution , but read and found a similar one to download but no luck :

```
   sap.ui.core.util.File.save();
```

Comment: The test application from SAP is fake. The upload does not work. Check F12 > Network. In a real app with a real backend it would work.

Comment: @Marc How do we know that a file is uploaded mate ? If so , does this data  `var oData = this.byId("UploadCollection").getModel("").getData();` is enough to POST ?

Comment: You need a backend which stores the upload somewhere.

Comment: @Marc oh i see , can you suggest any link that guides me through this ?

Comment: Depends on the type of backend you want/already have. SAP ABAP with OData? Something else?

Comment: Not SAP ABAP mate , we already have one , is that JAVA or DB , sorry what to answer idk

Comment: Sure @Marc , Thanks for suggestion :) all I was doing is They give an API to POST in a format , i was confused what to answer to your Q

Comment: Hey @Marc i have been reading a post there mentioned ...You need to show upload path to the upload collection before uploading.

For Example in your init / route matched or where ever you prefer:

`this.getView().byId("UploadCollection").setUploadUrl("/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZXXX/AttachmentSet");`   What should be the URl here ? an external API End point?

Comment: Yes. An endpoint which accepts post requests, and stores the incoming data stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When link is pressed, get base64 with a FileReader

```
var file = event.getSource().getParent().getFileObject();
var reader = new FileReader();
// call for file content
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
reader.onload = function (e) {
    var base64 = e.target.result;
}
```

Then create a Blob from base64 and open it as an iFrame:

```
var blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var myWindow = window.open("");
myWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='" + blobUrl + "'></iframe>");
myWindow.document.close();
```

But if you don't want to just open it in a new window you can download it as soon as you have a file content.

Comment: hey @Petr Becka i have been stuck while uploading ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052663/how-to-send-post-files-images-a-correct-format-from-frontend-to-backend-serv              ........ could you please help me out if you some time :)